# How to display Bitmap object in WinUI 3 application

Tags: c#, .net, image, winui-3, qrcoder

I want to display QR code generated by QRCoder library ( https://github.com/codebude/QRCoder/ ) in my WinUI 3 desktop app.

From QRCoder I get `System.Drawing.Bitmap` object:

```
            QRCodeGenerator qrCodeGenerator = new();
            QRCodeData qrCodeData = qrCodeGenerator.CreateQrCode(associateSoftwareTokenResponse.SecretCode, QRCodeGenerator.ECCLevel.Q);
            QRCode qrCode = new(qrCodeData);
            Bitmap qrCodeBitmap = qrCode.GetGraphic(20);
```

Then assigning it to XAML **Image** control: `qrCodeImage.Source = qrCodeBitmap` gives an error:

> Error CS0029  Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to
> 'Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Media.ImageSource'

So apparently there is still some conversion needed.

All documentation and examples I managed to find explain how to print an image from file but not Bitmap object.

How can I display this code generated Bitmap in my WinUI 3 app?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should be able to create a `BitmapImage` from a stream something like this:

```
Bitmap qrCodeBitmap = ...;
BitmapImage bitmapImage = new BitmapImage();
using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
{
    qrCodeBitmap.Save(stream, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);
    stream.Position = 0;
    bitmapImage.SetSource(stream.AsRandomAccessStream());
}
image.Source = bitmapImage;
```